# Python and MySql, alternative way to insert data into two tables that connected by for foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, insert

**Hello, I connected two MySql tables with foreign key and I want to insert data into them through python. here is the piece of code that works but there should be an alternative and professional way to do so otherwise I don't need foreign key and I just insert ID of first table customer_id column of the second table. thanks for helping.**

```
    Product = str(self.Text.GetValue())
    Product2 = str(self.Description.GetValue())       
    db=MySQLdb.connect('127.0.0.1', 'root','password', 'database') 
    cursor = db.cursor()  
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO customer (Address) VALUES (%s)", (Product))  
    cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM customer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    the_id= rows[0][0]
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO product_order (customer_id, description) VALUES (%s,%s)", (the_id,Product2))        
    cursor.execute("commit")
```

Comment: Professionally speaking I would be using a framework for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `db.insert_id()` to get the last inserted id/customer_id

Answer (score 0):

Err... [`the_id = cursor.lastrowid`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/).

Comment: Thanks. I like that way too, saves few lines of codes. even still don't know what would be the benefit of foreign key there.